# Não consigo recuperar o valor de id através do método POST

Tags: php, mysql, query

Tenho as seguintes funções:
Arquivo registra_conta.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['acao'])){
  if($_POST['acao'] == "inserir"){
    inserirConta();
}
if($_POST['acao'] == "alterar"){
    alterarConta();


function selectIdConta($id){
    $banco = abrirBanco();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM contas c INNER JOIN pessoa p ON(c.id_fornecedor = p.id) WHERE c.id = ".$id;
    $resultado = $banco->query($sql);
    $banco->close();
    $conta = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
    return $conta;
}



 function alterarConta(){
    $id_conta_selecionada = $_POST['id'];
    $sql = " UPDATE contas SET valor = '$valor' WHERE id= '$id_conta_selecionada' ";
    $banco->query($sql);
    $banco->close();
```

Percebi que se eu trocar o '$id_conta_selecionada' por um id cadastrado no banco, a query funciona, porém, através do método POST não estou conseguindo pegar o id da conta.

Arquivo alterar_conta.php:

```
<?php
    include_once("registra_conta.php");
    require_once("conexao.php");

    if(!$_SESSION['usuario']){
        header('Location: index.php?erro=1');
    }

    $conta = selectIdConta($_POST["id"]);

?>
```

Tenho o form:

```
<form name="dadosConta" action="registra_conta.php" method="POST">

<input type="hidden" name="acao" value="alterar">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$conta["id"]?>" />

        <div class="form-group">
            <button onclick="msgSucesso()" type="submit" value="Enviar" name="Enviar" class="btn customizado btn-roxo btn-lg">Alterar</button>
        </div>

</form>
```

Porque não estou conseguindo recuperar o id de conta??[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: posta por gentileza o código que prenche o valor desta variavel $conta["id"]

Comment: $conta = selectIdConta($_POST["id"]);

Comment: do lado de alterar no seu button coloca esse codigo php: .. <?php echo $conta["id"]; ?>  Alterar</button> se nao mostrar nada do lado de alterar é porque seu metodo esta errado

Comment: ahh ja sei vou responder

Comment: Apareceu "5", é o id do fornecedor, deveria pegar o id da conta. Provavelmente tem algo errado na minha query? Só não consigo encontrar onde.

Comment: é porque falou referenciar se o * é de qual tabela, contas ou pessoa. vou por na resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está na sua query do select.

altere isso:

```
SELECT * FROM contas c INNER JOIN pessoa p ON(c.id_fornecedor = p.id) WHERE c.id = ".$id
```

para isso:

```
SELECT c.* FROM contas c INNER JOIN pessoa p ON(c.id_fornecedor = p.id) WHERE c.id = ".$id
```

Pois como você disse nos comentários está aparecendo o id do fornecedor `5` e não tem contas com esse id.